# C# changing background and text color of DataTable columns

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

I have code like below, this code creates columns in Excel file.

```
foreach (DataColumn column in data.Columns)
{
columns.Add(new excelColumns() { columnName = column.ColumnName, columnDataType = column.DataType });

                    Cell cell = new Cell();
                    cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(column.ColumnName);
                    
                    headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
                }
```

I need to change background color and text colors of these columns. I can not find any solution for this. Can you help me?